# Mathematical objects

Tags: philosophy, foundations

If the essence of mathematical objects isn't important to mathematicians but rather what they do and how are they related is there a branch of science or mathematics itself that examines exactly this?

Comment: That examines exactly what? What the essence of mathematical objects is?

Comment: How are they created and what they mean.

Comment: See [Phylosophy of Mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/philosophy-mathematics/) and [Abstract Objects](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/abstract-objects/).

Comment: See e.g. John Burgess and Gideon Rosen, [A Subject with No Object](https://books.google.it/books?id=qjnEMSjEJocC), Oxford University Press (1977) as well as Hartry Field, [Science without Numbers](https://books.google.it/books?id=K8RLDQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Oxford UP (2nd ed., 2016).

Comment: Thank you all for providing useful links!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the branch of philosophy of mathematics known as [ontology of mathematics](https://philpapers.org/browse/ontology-of-mathematics). Citing from that page:

> Ontology of mathematics is concerned with the existence and nature of objects that mathematics is about.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess it is exactly what I am looking for!